# "Terminated due to Memory Pressure" with Sprite Kit, only when Xcode is attached

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory, sprite-kit

I am working on a Sprite Kit game, based on the Adventure sample code, that eventually throws up repeated memory warnings to the main view controller in the console, then finally, quits, and the alert message "Terminated due to Memory Pressure" occurs in Xcode.

This happens 100% of the time when connected to Xcode, but never when just running the app detached. I have released beta versions using Test Flight, and none of my testers have reported crashes. It only happens when Xcode is connected.

I have run Instruments and can find no leaks. The memory usage is reasonable and stays consistent. Can anyone suggest what might be going on here? It's something that never used to happen, but is really impeding my ability to debug now.

Comment: Do you have zombies enabled?

Comment: @sangony Yes, I do have zombies enabled in the current scheme I am using.

Comment: Having zombies active will ALWAYS lead to a memory crash because no objects are released.

Comment: @sangony Yep, I figured that out after your first post, thanks so much!